# IS multiplying by 1 a safe way to clean numeric values against sql injections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am wondering, If I have a value I know should be numeric, is multiplying it by 1 a safe method to clean it?

```
function x($p1){
   $p1*=1;
   sql="select * from t where id ={$p1}";
   //run query..
}
```

Although my example uses an ID, this is being used for many types of numeric values I have in my app (can be money, can be pai etc).

Comment: Why not intval? http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @MatTheCat and if my input is 3.14?

Comment: Would you ever have a non-int SQL id? You actually can't.

Comment: Theoretically, ID can be almost any legal field, including floats/decimals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't be.  But what's wrong with using prepared statements? That's always going to be safer than using PHP variables directly in SQL statements.

Comment: Generating complex dynamic queries is sometimes easier to code/maintain when you do not need to add the generation of dynamic parameters in the query.

Comment: @ItayMoav I would disagree. Since you can name the parameters and simply pass and assoc. array into `execute`, you can generate the query however you want and it is still easy to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more "appropriate" way, but for the scope of your question, I would say yes. If some sort of string is passed PHP will interpret it as a zero when doing the mathematical operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Comment: This would return false for decimal values like 1.4

Comment: But then `'3'` would be treated as a string. `is_numeric` is a better call.

Comment: [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) would be better

Comment: @ZachRattner, sorry, posted this before yours came up. No matter which solution the OP chose to go with though `'3'` would be treated as a string, and then ultimately as a zero value.

Comment: $p = '3' * 1;
echo $p;//prints 3

Comment: Also, instead of a single line of $p*=1; I would need to do much more logic...KISS

Comment: I took it as he meant `$p = "'3'" * 1;`

Comment: is_numeric might be better. But why would you have a float SQL id?

Answer (score 0):

While that'll probably work, `intval` seems like a better solution. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php. Your intent will likely be more obvious to someone else reading your code.

If you want to check if a value is numeric before converting it to an int, use `is_numeric` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php ). It'll check for strings that are numeric as well as integers. For example, if a number was coming back from a text input form via AJAX, it might be a string. In that case, `is_int` would return false, but `is_numeric` would return true.

**EDIT**

Now that I know you use DECIMAL for the MySQL column type, you can do something like this:

```
function getItem($pValue)
{

    if (!is_numeric($pValue))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $Query = sprintf
    (
        'SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %.2f',
        'TableName',
        'Price',
        $pValue
    );
    // Do something with $Query
}
```

Comment: Itay, unless you're dealing with gas, money is an integral value. It's just in cents and not dollars. This article is a good read: http://codemonkeyism.com/once-and-for-all-do-not-use-double-for-money/

Comment: I do not use double, I use decimal. This is a complication, I hate complex code.

Answer (score 0):

It works most of the times as it will cast strings to integers or doubles, but you have to be careful. It's going to work correctly for scalar values. However, if you do this:

```
x(new stdClass);
```

You'll get an `E_NOTICE`. This is not so bad, right? This:

```
x(array());
```

And you'll get an `E_ERROR`, *Unsupported operand types*, and the script terminates.

Maybe you'd think that it isn't so bad, but a fatal error at an inopportune moment can leave your system in an unstable state, per example, by losing referential integrity or leaving a series of queries unfinished.

Only you knows if a case like the above can happen. But if this data comes from a user in any way, I'd go with Murphy's Law on this one and not trust it.